# FileOpenPicker - customizing Cancel button text

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to customize button texts on a `FileOpenPicker` in a Windows 8 app. There is a `CommitButtonText` property but I can't see similar property for Cancel button. Is there a way to customize it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't customize. There's no property available. Only available option for you is to create own `FileOpenPicker`, which is quite time consuming task. BTW what you want to set as "cancel" button's text?

Comment: Localization may help you.